# Copy part of html tag to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementbyid

My php pages have some images in them, that I want to copy one of them to the `<meta property="og:image" content="" />` tag in the `head` section of the page.

Example of the image tag:

```
<img class="img-responsive" border="0" src="../../../Gallery/path/file.jpg" alt="some text" width="640" height="460">
```

Expected output (to be added to the  section) that trims everything from the above line, and just takes the path of the image from it:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="../../../Gallery/path/file.jpg" />
```

I tried somethings in the line with `getElementById` and `innerHTML` but it's not working.  Also something like: `jQuery( "img.img-responsive" );`, (but it takes the whole line). I think it needs something like `.removeAttr()` but I am not sure how implement all that together.

- *Another thing*, and I am not sure if it is doable: If the page has more classes with the same name but with different images, is it possible to specify in the jQuery or Javascript code which image to use? (for example adding `,1` for the first image, or `,2` to copy only the second?

Comment: You answered your own question. " jQuery( "img.img-responsive" ); (but it takes the whole line). " You can do a php function called strpos($haystack, $needle) to find your src part and save it in content. Let me know if i was helpful and you need a demo for that.

Comment: @HassaanAli Thanks for the reply, a demo would be great to test.

Comment: How is this a "php" question?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It's just that I'll be using that script in php.. But you are right, I removed the php tag..

Comment: Thanks Mike :) It makes a question unclear I feel as well as being (a tad) misleading for those such as I that follow that tag, had it been a php-related issue.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `attr()` http://api.jquery.com/attr/ and `eq()` https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

```
$('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content', $('.img-responsive:eq(2)').attr('src') ); // eq(2) for the 3rd image
```

---